# How can I find the roots of this for k?

Tags: roots

$$ln(1-e^{-kx})(1-e^{-kx})+kxe^{-kx}=0$$

I need to find $k$ in this equation , it should be a function of $x$. Any hints on how should I do it ?

Comment: Numerical ...!!!.

Comment: Is this $$\ln(1-e^{-kx})^2+kxe^{-kx}=0$$?

Comment: no its $ln(x)*x$ where $x = 1 - e^{-kx}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $t = e^{-kx}$, your equation says
$$ (1-t) \ln(1-t) = t \ln(t) $$
Rather obviously $t=1/2$ is a solution.  There are no other real solutions (unless you count $t=0$ and $t=1$).